# 5.5.52-MariaDB with Magento 2 will it work properly

Tags: magento2, database

I am trying to import Magento 2 database on 5.5.52-MariaDB.
while it was import I got an error the import stop at admin_user 
ERROR: 
**"MySQL Error There can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT clause"**

I am wondering if 5.5.52-MariaDB isn't the right version and that's why I am getting this error.

As per [Magento 2 Docs](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/magento/system-requirements.html) it does not say which version of MariaDB it requires.
Does anybody knows or have more imformation about this?
Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.0 and 2.1 require MySQL 5.6 or 5.7.

MariaDB 5.5 is equivalent to MySQL 5.5, meaning it is not compatible with Magento 2. You'll need to upgrade to MariaDB 10 to install Magento 2 on it.

According to [their download page](https://downloads.mariadb.org/), MariaDB 10.1 is the current stable release, concurrent with MySQL 5.6 and 5.7.

Comment: Thank's Ryan. That's helps me to proceed and upgrade to MariaDB 10.

Comment: @JulianoVargas Great. If an answer solves your issue, please vote it up and mark as accepted.